# Message Box yesnoButtons in windows phone 7.5

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

In window phone 7.5 . I  want to use yes no buttons in message box  . But there is no option for yes no buttons in message box. How can i use with yes no  buttons  or other alternate to show  caption (OK =yes and cancel =no) 
Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Coding4Fun MessagePrompt to create Yes/No message with custom buttons in this way:

```
        MessagePrompt messagePrompt = new MessagePrompt();
        messagePrompt.Message = "Some Message.";
        Button yesButton = new Button() { Content = "Yes" };
        yesButton .Click += new RoutedEventHandler(yesButton _Click);
        Button noButton = new Button() { Content = "No" };
        noButton .Click += new RoutedEventHandler(noButton _Click);
        messagePrompt.ActionPopUpButtons.Add(noButton);
        messagePrompt.ActionPopUpButtons.Add(yesButton );
        messagePrompt.Show();
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use the [Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.gamerservices.guide.aspx) class from the XNA framework.  There is a BeginShowMessageBox method giving you the option to pass in whatever strings you wish for the buttons.

Answer (score 1):

The other option is to use [MessagePrompt](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MessagePrompt) from Coding4fun toolkit and customize according to your needs

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the problem with WP MessageBox is that it only supports the OK and OKCancel MessageBoxButton, which means that you’re limited to either an ok button or an ok and a cancel button. The YesNo and YesNoCancel enumeration values are not supported.

Basically you can try to display a semi-transparent blanking layer over the page content,  and then display a custom message box on top of that. [Here](http://cloudstore.blogspot.fr/2011/01/customizing-messagebox-on-windows-phone.html), you can find a complete sample.

Another option is to use a custom library like [Windows Phone Assets](http://wpassets.codeplex.com/).